# Null safety error with flutter_dotenv on Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, package, dotenv, dart-null-safety

I am new to Flutter, and I have an error that I don't understand when I try to use the flutter_dotenv package.

I added the dependency

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_dotenv: ^3.1.0
```

but when I try the import

```
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart' as DotEnv;
```

it returns me that.

```
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

 - package:flutter_dotenv
```

Can you help me ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

the messages sounds like you are using already sdk environment null safety.

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0"
```

Any version from 2.12 included, demands packages and libraries to upgrade null safety, you can watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_VrulBiOV_o) to know what's about.

If that's the case you should use the following version:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dotenv/versions/4.0.0-nullsafety.0

```
dependencies:
  flutter_dotenv: ^4.0.0-nullsafety.0
```

Comment: Yes, I need change sdk version, else I have an error on this line.
`const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);`